# Limit Max number of Link connections in Joint.js Elements

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

I'm using Joint.js to design a diagram designer and I want to limit the MAX number of connections from-and-to an element to 2 connections. (if condition in flowchart diagram). how can I do that?

I'm using

```
var link = new joint.shapes.basic.Link({});
```

and

```
var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({});
```

for creating links and element.

Thanks.